# Algorithm to calculate point at which to round values in an array up or down in order to least affect the mean

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, search, mean

Consider array random array of values between 0 and 1 such as:

[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.9]

is there a way to calculate the point at which the values should be rounded down or up to an integer in order to match the mean of the un-rounded array the closest? (in above case it would be at the mean but that is purely a coincidence)

or is it just trial and error?
im coding in python

thanks for any help

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd also post a desired output (just to make things more obvious). For example in this case you'd like the output to be [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them up, then round the sum. That's how many 1s you want. Round so you get that many 1s.

```
def rounding_point(l):
    # if the input is sorted, you don't need the following line
    l = sorted(l)
    ones_needed = int(round(sum(l)))
    # this may require adjustment if there are duplicates in the input
    return 1.0 if ones_needed == len(l) else l[-ones_needed]
```

If sorting the list turns out to be too expensive, you can use a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) like quickselect. Python doesn't come with a quickselect function built in, though, so don't bother unless your inputs are big enough that the asymptotic advantage of quickselect outweighs the constant factor advantage of the highly-optimized C sorting algorithm.

Comment: `l[-ones_needed]` would raise TypeError since `ones_needed` is not an integer and therefore cannot be used as an index. EDIT: another minor issue is that you might want to return something from the function :)